# How do you listen on change events in the model from a view using the shorthand 'events' object?

Tags: backbone.js

I've got the following BackboneJS view, which has a model:

```
view = Backbone.View.extend({
   events: {
       // This will fire btnClicked() when the button is clicked
       "click .btn": "btnClicked",

       // Will this fire when the "data" property of my model changes?
       "change:data": "render"
   },
   btnClicked: function() {},
   render: function() {}
});
```

Any idea if it is possible to use this shortcut?

If not, the extended form would be:

```
this.model.bind("change:data", render);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That events map is for views to listen to UI events, not for wiring up data events.

The Documentation on [Views](http://backbonejs.org/#View-delegateEvents) states

> Uses jQuery's on function to provide declarative callbacks for DOM
>   events within a view.

So the View's event map can't be used for model events.

Answer (score 1):

As Kyle said, the `events` hash is for delegating DOM events to the view object.

Something worth adding, you should usually use the `listenTo` form instead of the `bind` approach as this will handle the event cleanup for you (one of the main upsides of using the `events` hash for DOM events).

```
this.listenTo(this.model, "change:data", render);
```